# Dom-repeat doesn't work in tables in IE in polymer 2.0?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.0

```html
<div style='height:calc(100% - 31px);overflow:auto;'>
    <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" multi>
     <juicy-table-repeat  rows="{{allAlbums}}">
          <tr>
            <td style='vertical-align: middle;'>
              <paper-checkbox class="styled sizeCheckbox" value="[[item]]" 
                on-change="_addProductInAlbum">
                [[item.albumName]]
              </paper-checkbox>
            </td>
          </tr> 
     </juicy-table-repeat>
    </paper-listbox>
 </div>
```

Hello sir,
 i have create web application in which dom-repeat is properly work in chrome browser but in the IE it is not working inside the table tag.i am using

Answer (score 0):

`dom-repeat` does *NOT* work in tables IE, you are correct. The issue is tracked by the Polymer team [here](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1567).